# Profiling native c++ applications in VS 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, profiling

I have a mixed project (C#, C++/CLI, and native C++) that I'm trying to profile in VS 2012. When I run the Profiler, I get sampling results for the managed code, but all of the native code is shown under the entry `"dynamicClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke"`, i.e. I don't have any debug symbols loaded. The managed pdb and native pdb files are in the same location; what am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my experience (with an OLD version of VTune, and the old version of visual studio that didn't let you do mixed debugging, so I don't know if it is valid) you can only profile managed or unmanaged at one time. The way to trick it into doing the unmanaged dll is to set the unmanaged dll as the startup project and tell it to launch the managed code. No idea if this is helpful in 2012 at all :-P